# ListView with load more and url images

Tags: android

I need to make an android page with ListView that show url images with load more
Can anyone inset to me one source example that contain remote image and load more with JSON in android listview??
I need them together

Comment: These are two separate questions - you should edit your question to better describe one of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a footerView containing Load More Button to the ListView. refer this tutorial

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/

Comment: an example with load more and remote images with json

Comment: you can make out of this tutorial whatever your requriements. Here text is being fetched from server, you can have image url.